# Do I need to remove GRUB after installing windows 10

Tags: linux, windows-10, installation

My computer is currently running ubuntu, but I want to install windows 10 instead.
I have a bootable flash drive with windows 10 in it. The question is will windows automatically remove GRUB after installation, or do I need to do it manually like described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on ?

The reason why I am not sure is because the link above is for windows 7.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instructions give by Emerson Hsieh at https://askubuntu.com/a/143482 are very peculiar and at least don't apply to Windows 10. Per my experience, Windows 10 overwrites the master boot record with its own, regardless of whether you perform a nuke-and-reload or a side-along installation.

As long as you make correct choices in Windows partition selection screen, GRUB is removed for good.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you mean, that you don't want to dual boot, but instead erase Ubuntu and install Windows right?

That should be no problem, in the windows installer you need to remove every partition and then create the windows partition. Grub should lie at the first ~100MB of your hard disk in /dev/sda1, which is mount to /boot/efi.

EDIT: In Windows installer will you need to do manual partitioning. But this is pretty much the same wizard in any windows version.

Comment: So I don't need to do the steps described here? http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on

Comment: I think that guide doesn't address your situation. You need to do this, if you installed Ubuntu next to Windows and want to overwrite GRUB with the Windows boot loader. If your whole disk is used by Ubuntu now and you want to use the whole disk with Windows, just do the normal Windows installation procedure.